# Why phpunit is green when there are tons of exceptions?

Tags: phpunit

Why phpunit is green when there are tons of exceptions?

Here's an example job in travis: https://travis-ci.org/ConnectCorp/nexmo-client/jobs/79275172

```
Strict standards: Declaration of Nexmo\Tests\Service\TestServiceTrait::exec() should be compatible with Nexmo\Service\Service::exec($params, $method = 'GET') in /home/travis/build/ConnectCorp/nexmo-client/tests/Service/VoiceTest.php on line 42
Call Stack:
    0.0013     415584   1. {main}() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0209    1038200   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit:722
    0.0209    1044680   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:104
    0.0209    1045112   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:114
    0.0281    1812016   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php:664
    0.0281    1812928   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Configuration.php:814
    0.0318    2063368   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Configuration.php:901
    0.1145    6533504   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() /home/travis/build/ConnectCorp/nexmo-client/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:403
    0.1145    6571744   9. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /home/travis/build/ConnectCorp/nexmo-client/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:331
    0.1146    6571880  10. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:42
    0.1148    6681536  11. include_once('/home/travis/build/ConnectCorp/nexmo-client/tests/Service/VoiceTest.php') phar:///home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.37/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php:58
PHPUnit 4.8.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
...............................................................  63 / 117 ( 53%)
......................................................
Time: 511 ms, Memory: 13.00Mb
OK (117 tests, 210 assertions)
```

https://travis-ci.org/ConnectCorp/nexmo-client/jobs/79275172

I would expect it would fail and travis report that a build has failed, but it just silently passes. Is there any phpunit config option I am missing?

Current phpunit config is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true"
         bootstrap="./vendor/autoload.php"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Nexmo Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor/*</directory>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though there is an error, no tests have actually failed, so phpunit will return a success code.

Before running the tests, phpunit first loads and parses `*Test.php` files and this is where your errors are coming from, rather than from a test method itself.

Changing the config option `stopOnFailure="false"` to `stopOnFailure="true"` or `stopOnError="true"` should make this task fail.

From the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html):

> --stop-on-error           Stop execution upon first error.
>
> --stop-on-failure         Stop execution upon first error or failure.

**Edit**

Actually, just been playing with this and as it is a notice and before the tests actually start those flags won't have any effect.

Comment: yes, this makes sense, thanks. So basically a solution for this could be moving any code that is not a test into separate files. In this case it would be autoloaded during test execution and would fail as expected.

Comment: Yes, in general your tests will be in files dedicated to tests, and you will have one class in each file. You then rely on the auto-loading (via a bootstrap) to load the class definitions as they're mentioned. This also eliminates the need for `include`/`require` blocks at the top of files.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to discovered a bug in phpunit and I suggest you report it to [their repository](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/).

It only seems to be a problem if a notice is triggered from the test class. Your mock classes are defined in the same file as a test class. If you move them out to its own file tests will start failing as expected. Methods need to have the same signature as their parent.

Might be also worth to configure error reporting in your `phpunit.xml` to report all errors (although this alone will not solve your current issue, error reporting will be enable no matter how environment is configured):

```php
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
</php>
```

Comment: yes, correct. But I don't think it's a bug or if it is even fixable - tests haven't started yet. Moving mock files outside of the tests sounds like a solution for that.

Comment: I consider it a bug. It shouldn't matter how PHPUnit autoloads tests. You've got errors during test execution time (doesn't matter in which phase phpunit is).